# UITableView delegate is not getting called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using the `UITableView` in a menu drawer and changing the place of the UITableView upon clicking the menu button.

The `UITableViewDataSource` is working, the `UITableViewDelegate` are not working.
I set the delegate from story board and inside view controller still
the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is not getting called.

```
-(void) showMenu{
isMenuShown = YES;
        [_drawerButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"v_drawer_menu"]];
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(220, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
        _tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.origin.y, 220, self.view.frame.size.height);
        self.menuView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.origin.y, 220, self.view.frame.size.height);
        _menuView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        _tableView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        _tableView.delegate = self;

        [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

[image: The view and table view I am moving them upon toggle.]
Help appreciated.

The issue is **RESOLVED**,

I was moving the base view so all interactions were on base with with x position from 220 hence the table view interactions were not working, I changed the view hierarchy in story board and used the `bringSubviewToFront` method of view to make it working.

Thank you :)

Comment: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {}not called when numberOfRowsInSection returns nil or 0

Comment: Try to put break point in noOfRowsInSection function. If It calls then try to see how many row you are returning from this function.

Comment: The data source method is working fine, facing issue in the delegate methods only.

Comment: check in numberOfRowsInSection method means debug it once

Comment: Dude. is your code rendering the cells or not..??

Comment: Yes it is rendering the cells...

Comment: numberOfRowsInSection returns value or not?

Comment: Ok. then you need to check whether the cell are enable or not. If you have set setEnable = false then you are not able to touch or click on to the cell. and I request you to set datasource and delegate from the code base (in viewWillAppear method) .

Comment: Ok I will give try for it, and yes numberOfRowsInSection is returning the array count i.e 7.

Comment: I set the data source and delegate in viewDidLoad and viewWilAppear. Still the same issue and the setEnable property in UITableViewCall or in tableview either

Comment: have you using AutoLayout?

Comment: Yes I m using autoLayout

Comment: check constraints once properly because of constraints some times it happen

Comment: Add a different UITableViewDelegate method to your controller to make sure that the delegate is getting set properly -- something that will get called all the time like: tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: -- if that gets called then it's likely something to do with your table view not recognizing the touches for some reason. Provide more explanations of what you are doing so we can help.

Comment: Ya i even tried it, the tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath is getting called and updated the tableview cell height. I am suspecting that the frame change which I am doing is causing issue.

Comment: Check whether your Tableview and Tableviewcell selection state.

Comment: This has happened to me before: I selected didDeselectRowAtIndexPath instead of didSelect... from the auto-complete list, so it seems like it was never called.  Double check that your method name for didSelect is *exactly* right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is not getting then there may be one of the following reason.

1. delegate is not set. This I understand is set properly to the file owners.
2. There may be a UI control in the table view cell which is as same size as the cell.
3. A `UIView` which can respond to touch in the responder chain.
4. Or may be the table view is `allowsSelectionDuringEditing` is `flase`.

Comment: Looks like the UI VIEW is responding to the events, I have updated my question how the storyboard is designed.

Comment: The issue is resolved now, Since I was moving the main view the view controls were also limited to Main view hence the interactions were nt working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check few things:

- It some time happens that if we have copied tableview from some other viewcontroller than delegate & datasource links will be already there but pointing to that old view controller. So need to remove the link & again make connection
- Also make sure You have not put UITableViewDelegate protocol in your .h file as because you already linked on storyboard
- If still it not work than clean your project & remove delegate method, than put cursor on UITableview Press window key. You will be redirected to the page of delegate methods of tableview & copy delegate method from it & place it in your code.

(Note: Do not copy delegate methods from any where, its good practice to direct copy it from delegate section page).

Hope this will help you to resolve the issue.